# Kick or kick off a discussion?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

When you want to say "starting a thread to discuss something", is it more correct saying "kick a discussion" or "kick off a discussion"?
Thank you.

Comment: It's "Kick off the discussion on [whatever]", and your heart is in the right place.

Comment: "Kickoff" (as one word) is also a sports term, referring to the start of a soccer or American football match, when the ball is put into play by kicking it. Not sure which usage came first, although I'd suspect the very literal sports usage.

Comment: @Matt: I wouldn't know. I'm a hockey fan. You know. _Hockey sur glace_. Let's go Rangers and all that.

Comment: "2. Informal To begin; start" *Am. Heritage*. I voted to close your question because it is immediately answerable with commonly available general reference materials--in this case, the online *American Heritage* dictionary: see [The Free Dictionary](http://thefreedictionary.com/kick-off).

Comment: "Kick off" is idiomatic, from several sports games where a "kick off" starts the game.  "Kick" is on rare occasions used to mean "shake up", eg, to add a question or comment which "livens" a "dead" discussion.

Answer (score 1):

In this sense, it's been used with "off", i.e. "*kick off sth*" , "*kick off sth with*". It can be used transitively or intransitively.

Another meaning of the term is: " to remove your shoes by shaking your feet", as in:
"*She kicked off her shoes and danced barefoot.*"

Answer (score 1):

It's ***'kick off*** a discussion', which comes from the sport of football (or soccer, as it's called in the US), in which a ball is kicked around a field by two teams of 11 players.

*Kick off* time is the time that a match starts; the first kick of the game. The Online Etymology Dictionary lists the figurative usage of this word as beginning in [1875](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=kick-off).

> Also *kickoff*, *kick-off*, 1857, "first kick in a football match," from *kick* (v.) + *off*. Figurative sense of "start, beginning event" is from 1875.